# NSTask setLaunchPath Objective-C Cocca

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstask

This is a very simple question. I have a script in the same folder as the Cocoa app. I can't seem to set the path to it properly for `setLaunchPath` for `NSTask`. Help please.

I have a folder called Project. Inside of it, exist multiple folders but only two we care about: `Classes` (the source files for the Cocoa app are here) and Ruby (which is a ruby server folder). I am trying to call `Ruby/script/server`. I assumed it would be something like `./Ruby/script/server` or `Ruby/script/server` but both are wrong.

Thanks.

EDIT: I guess what I'm actually asking is if there is a way to access the folder where the source files or the project is by using a special character or shortcut because by default it goes to the `/tmp` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current directory (in the unix sense) in an app is not guaranteed to be anything. The path to the app itself can be obtained by getting the main app bundle by

```
NSBundle*mainBundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
```

and then getting its path

```
NSString*path=[mainBundle bundlePath];
```

**However** please don't do that; you won't be able to distribute your app without extra instructions of putting files here and there.
Instead, put your Ruby code inside `yourApp.app/Contents/Resources/`. This can be done by including the Ruby code in the XCode, and making sure it's set to be copied into the app. The files inside this `Resources` directory can be obtained as follows:

```
NSString*path=[mainBundle pathForResource:@"rubyServer" ofType:@"rb"];
```

To learn more about the bundle structure, read [Bundle Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i).